# Can't add objects to array instance var by block

Tags: iphone, geolocation, block, instance-variables

I would like to add objects to an instance var of type NSMutableArray, that I am creating in a block (reverseGeocodeLocation). I can see the value in the defined objects. But I can't get it to work, to add them to the instance var.

I already thought about the __block or __strong prefix. But I seem to miss something out. Can you give me a clue? The instance var "tableviewRows" is still empty after running the code in the block.

Thank you!
Sebastian

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            CLLocation *userLocation = [placemark location];

            NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat. %f degrees", userLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long. %f degrees", userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            NSString *altitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alt. %f m", userLocation.altitude];
            NSString *speed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Speed %f m/s", userLocation.speed];
            NSString *course = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Course %f degrees", userLocation.course];

            [self.tableViewRows insertObject:latitude atIndex:0];
            [self.tableViewRows insertObject:longitude atIndex:1];
            [self.tableViewRows insertObject:altitude atIndex:2];
            [self.tableViewRows insertObject:speed atIndex:3];
            [self.tableViewRows insertObject:course atIndex:4];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload your table after the background operation finishes. So it should be in the completion handler.

Try this

```
__block NSArray *dataArray;

[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation 
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
//...

   dataArray = @[latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, course];
   NSLog(@"Just checking... %@", dataArray);
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      self.tableViewRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataArray];
      [self.tableView reloadData];
   });
 }];
```

Comment: Hi.. .Nope... just tried that. Still getting the error: "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"

Comment: This means that you are on the right track. Now you just have to step through your code and make sure yuor datasource array is properly populated.

Comment: well.. I just did that as well.. I can see, that the data is in the completion block. but it won't populate the instance var array. Seems they are getting lost after the block has finished.

Comment: how would I do that? I thought it should be possible to access an instance var directly in the block?

Comment: sorry for that.. I just tried it.. Still getting this message. "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29045/discussion-between-konturgestaltung-and-mundi)

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged it some more.. but still the same strange thing ..... The array self.tableViewRows is being filled with data INSIDE the block. But as soon as I try a "count" on the array outside, the value returned is 0. Inside the block it is 5, as it should be?!?